# Uses of FUSE filesystems

Tags: fuse

I recently used a FUSE filesystem to mount my Google Drive on to a folder in my computer using this tutorial:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/mount-google-drive-in-linux-with-google.html

I found this very useful, and it got me wondering if there are any other ways of using FUSE filesystems. By this I mean in general everyday use.

Comment: you could use a VPS. have super-level access to its OS. install any software that runs on it.